# how to fill soapaction field in the soap request using csoap client

Tags: soap, soap-client

I am trying to send a soap request to two soap server, from first server i am able to receive the response but from second server i am receiving an HTTP error 500(internal server error). I took TCP dump and analysed the error which is [ISS.0088.9166] Binder not found for soapAction = , i find that in the request soapAction is missing though it is mentioned in the WSDL.

I have developed the soap client using csoap. I couldn't able to find any sample code in which  it is explained to fill the soapAction field.

Appreciate your comment on the same.

Thanks,
AH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found in the csoap documentation, below API support for the soapAction field.

herror_t soap_client_invoke(struct SoapCtx * ctx, struct SoapCtx ** response, const char * url, const char * **soap_action**)

Thanks, AH